# Notepad++ Removing spaces between certain words

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I'm having an issue using Notepad++ and trying to remove the two spaces in between the ID's on the document.

EX:

```
ID = 10103
ID = 10104
ID = 61016
```

I'm trying to remove ONLY the two spaces between ID and the number. So 'ID = 10103' turns into 'ID=10103' for example. The document has a few thousand of these ID's. Is there some way to mass replace the entire document so the spaces are only the two spaces are removed from the 'ID = _' lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just directly match the `ID = num` expressions:

```regex
Find:    \bID = (\d+)\b
Replace: ID=$1
```

### Demo

Note that if you are not sure whether there would be whitespace on both sides of the `=` sign, you could use `\bID\s*=\s*(\d+)\b`.  However, this would match every `ID` line, even those which are already in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the job,

Find what: `ID\K = (?=\d)`
Replace with: `=`